# Creating a Grid in WGS 84 in Feet

Tags: wgs84, grids-graticules

I am using Using QGIS 18.16 to try and create a grid measured in feet.
I am having some issues with the best way to create a accurate grid in a project projected in WGS 84.  I know that it uses degrees but i need to come up with a way to create it in feet.  I have tried the Vector Grid creation and a few plugins but i feel like i am missing something and making this a little to hard.

Answer (score 3):

WGS84 coordinates are coordinates on a spheroid. You can't have a regular grid on a spheroid.

Over a small area you can use another coordinate system that is planar and make a regular grid with that, but it won't be a regular grid if you transform it to WGS84 (lat-long) coordinates.

Comment: But be aware that a *grid* created in a projected coordinate system will not be regular when viewed/projected to geographic coordinates.. my advice is to make your map in a suitable projected coordinate system otherwise your grid will look funny and your scale bar would be unusable at best.